# How do i update the networkx from version 1.6 to 1.7?

Tags: python, networkx

All_shortest_paths is not working in version 1.6 and i would like to update it to version 1.7. Is there a simple update command i can use?

Comment: Have you tried to download and install v1.7?

Comment: Just install the new version the same way you installed 1.6. Some tools, like `pip`, will require an extra flag like `--upgrade`, but that's the only wrinkle.

Answer (score 5):

Just type

`pip install networkx --upgrade`

This would get you the latest release of Networkx ( 1.10 as of now).